# getClientOriginalName() on null and $request->hasFile('image') not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on uploading some text and image to database. I'm getting an error :

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

when below code is used:

```
$file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName(); // 'image' is name in html form.
```

But `$file = $request->input('image');` gets image name.

(also `if($request->hasFile('image'))` is not work (it returns FALSE).)

In my html,

```html
<form method="post" action="/postupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="file" name="image">
</form>
```

In my controller,

```php
public function upload(Request $request) {

$title = $request->input('title');

if($request->hasFile('image')) {

$file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$image->move(public_path('images'), $file);

$post = new Post();
$is_success = $post->addPost($title, $file);
}

}
```

Comment: Does your file meet the requirements? Maybe it's too big?

Answer (score 0):

When you access the uploaded file using the $request->file() method, it returns an instance of php's native SplFileInfo class. By looking at the php manual, you can see which methods are available on that class, check it out here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

Also, take a look at the Laravel's docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files

To further extend the answer: Should you need to do something with your file that the SplFileInfo cannot do,  you can retrieve the newly uploaded file via the Storage Facade, which is built on top of the Flysystem package that will give you a ton of options for working with files. Start by reading up on the File Storage Larave'ls docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#retrieving-files

Answer (score 0):

Use instead of that

```
$request->file('upload_file');
var_dump($request->file('upload_file'));
```